# SPARK - Can't read multiline JSON (corrupt_record: string (nullable = true))

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I'm looking for recommendation about the Title's issue. I've read in databricks (https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-json.html) that I can read to a dataframe a multi-line json with the following expression:

```html
 println("2.2 Dataframe Multiline")
       MULTILINE MODE!!
    val df2=spark.read.option("multiline","true").option("charset","UTF-8").json("EXPORT1.json")
    df2.printSchema()
```

This is not working for me. If I remove manually all the breaklines from the JSON this is the resulting schema:

```html
root
 |-- results: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- address_components: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- long_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- short_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- types: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- formatted_address: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- geometry: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- bounds: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- northeast: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- lng: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- southwest: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- lng: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- lng: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- location_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- viewport: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- northeast: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- lng: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- southwest: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- lng: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- place_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- types: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- status: string (nullable = true)+
```

And this is an example JSON I download from Google:

```html
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "30152",
               "short_name" : "30152",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Murcia",
               "short_name" : "Murcia",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Murcia",
               "short_name" : "MU",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Region of Murcia",
               "short_name" : "Region of Murcia",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Spain",
               "short_name" : "ES",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "30152 Murcia, Spain",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.9659196,
                  "lng" : -1.1346723
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.9442828,
                  "lng" : -1.1687921
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.9569734,
               "lng" : -1.1496969
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.9659196,
                  "lng" : -1.1346723
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.9442828,
                  "lng" : -1.1687921
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJZbDcb0Z_Yw0RUK0TPnKvAhw",
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

As I want to get many petitions to Google, I can't remove breaklines manually.

Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if the json file size is not so huge you can use `spark.read.json(sc.wholeTextFiles(EXPORT1.json).values)` to get json records.

Comment: The problem is that im using sparksesion instead of spark contexts so I couldn't manage to resolve the issue...

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the issue what I did was storing the JSON removing all line breaks:

The Following class takes the address, component, ... and write the Geolocation petition into a JSON

```html
class Geolocation(var Address: String, var Component: String, var APIKey: String,  var JSONName:Int ){
 val GeoLocURL_REQ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+Address+"&components="+Component+"&key="+APIKey
  val filename=JSONName.toString+"_LatLon.json"
  val file = new File(filename)
  val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
  val svc = url(GeoLocURL_REQ)
  val response : Future[String] = Http(svc OK as.String)

  response onComplete {
    case Success(content) => {
      println("worked!" + content)
      bw.write(content.replaceAll("\\s", ""))  //con un \\n va
      //bw.write(content)
      bw.close()
    }
    case Failure(t) => {
      println("failed:! " + t.getMessage)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
import dispatch._, Defaults._


  var APIKey="TYPE YOUR OWN API HERE"
    var PostalCode=30152
    var Localidad = "Murcia"
    val Component="postal_code="+PostalCode+"%7Ccountry=ES"  // "|" = %7C
    var Address=Localidad+"+"+PostalCode

    val geolocation= new Geolocation(Address,Component,APIKey, PostalCode )
```

Hope this help someone!